# when upload file to github, occur error?

Tags: git, file-upload, github

When I try to remotely connect github on git shell, but return this error, and I don't hnow how to handle it.

```
C:\Users\wt> ssh –t git@github.com
ssh.exe": Could not resolve hostname \342\200\223t: no address associated with name
C:\Users\wt> ssh -t git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.128' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate your public key and add it to your github account.
Then you need to make sure you have added your private key to your ssh.
This linke should help(follow each step) : https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: when i login, a error was return. unable to retieve your user info from the server.a proxy server might be interfering with the request. Is my .net Framework not the lastest?

Comment: You need to remove the key that was preciously added by you to the known hosts file. Please follow the link: http://superuser.com/questions/30087/remove-key-from-known-hosts. If you  don't have any other hosts, you can use this command: rm -f .ssh/known_hosts